# Reference request for Deterministic $\subset$ Random $\subset$ Quantum

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, c-star-algebras, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I hope this post is on topic as a reference request.

I have seen somewhere the idea of (and saw it written just like this):

$$\text{Deterministic }\subset\text{ Random }\subset\text{ Quantum }.$$

I am writing a note and want to use this idea and am just wondering is there a good reference where such matters are discussed. To explain what the above means in my context see below the fold.

---

I have a situation where I have a non-commutative $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $A\subset B(\mathsf{H})$, which for the purposes of this question can be taken to be finite dimensional. Let $\mathsf{H}=\ell^2(X)\oplus\ell^2(Y)$.

$X$ is the set of *deterministic objects*, and each $\mathbb{C}e_x$ is $A$-invariant. Therefore if I am measuring $e_x$ (in the sense of quantum mechanics) with a projection $p\in A$ I am getting yes (1) or no (0) with probabilities 0/1 or 1/0.

With the help of the Born Rule I can take elements of the projective Hilbert space, superpositions, $P(\ell^2(X))$ and consider these as *random objects*. As $A$ restricted to $\ell^2(X)$ is commutative, it doesn't matter in which order I make measurements, but there is a probabilistic aspect.

$A$ restricted to $\ell^2(X)$ is commutative but suppose the non-commutativity kicks in for $\ell^2(Y)$. Suppose $Y=\{y_1,y_2\}$, and suppose $A$ restricted to $\ell^2(Y)$ is $M_2(\mathbb{C})$. If we measure $e_{y_1}+e_{y_2}\in P(\mathsf{H})$, with say, where
$$p=\frac12\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & e^{-i\pi/4}\\ e^{i\pi/4}&1\end{array}\right),$$
first with $p$ (record and collapse), then $p^T$ (record and collapse), then $p$ again, and calculating probabilities using inner products, we find that the probability that we find $p=1$ then $p^T=1$ then $p=0$ --- impossible for *random objects* --- is non-zero.

So $\text{Deterministic }\subset\text{ Random }\subset\text{ Quantum }$ is captured here by:

$$P(\mathbb{C}e_x)\subset P(\ell^2(X))\subset P(\mathsf{H}).$$

Comment: I _think_ this philosophy occurs when studying quantum games (which are currently fashionable; i.e. a lot of progress is being made).  Classical means "deterministic" strategy, and obviously this is a subset of random.  The magic occurs when you use quantum entaglement to get joint distrubtions which cannot arise from classical probability (but are "physical").  Mathematically I suspect it's rather similar to your description.  I encourage someone who knows more about this than I do to write something...

Comment: In the context of quantum games, classical and random are actually equal to each other (i.e., if you can win a game with a certain probability via a strategy with randomization, then there must be a deterministic strategy that achieves the same probability of winning, by a convexity argument).

Comment: Thank you folks: it is deterministic not classical I surely want. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I might argue for the converse $\text{Deterministic }\supset\text{ Random }\supset\text{ Quantum }$, in the sense that a large ensemble of deterministic bits can be reduced to a  smaller number of quasi-random bits, which can be further reduced to an even smaller number of quantum mechanically random bits ("randomness amplification").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I interpret your question is: deterministic = pure state on an abelian C${}^*$-algebra, random = arbitrary state on an abelian C${}^*$-algebra, quantum = pure state on an arbitrary C${}^*$-algebra. There's one further level of generality, arbitrary state on an arbitrary C${}^*$-algebra, which gives you statistical ensembles of quantum states.

(Note that under this interpretation you do not have "random $\subset$ quantum", unless your "quantum" includes ensembles.)

Comment: Thank you Nik... is there a good reference where this kind of idea might be written down (and explored a little)?

Comment: I'd recommend Chapter 7 of *Hilbert Space Operators in Quantum Physics* by Blank, Exner, and Havlicek.

Comment: You are welcome!